# ajax response unresponsive due to jquery selector

Tags: ajax, jquery

there is a div with a class designation of:

```
<div class="box info-box">
```

I am getting a section of code using AJAX, how can I replace this part using a response and jquery's replacewith method?

```
jQuery('.box info-box').replaceWith(data.tooltip);
```

doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to target one element that has two or more classes, you use no space and a second period, like `jQuery('.box.info-box')` or if you don't need both classes to be present, you can just do `jQuery('.box')` or `jQuery('.info-box')`

I suggest posting questions like this on the general Stack Exchange page, as it's not specific to Magento.